# Option: number of digits

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

The command

```
NestList[Cos, 1.5, 10]
```

produces the list:

```
{0.750313, 0.731476, 0.74419, 0.735637, 0.741403, 0.737522,
 0.740137, 0.738376, 0.739563, 0.738763, 0.739302}
```

What is an easy way to have each number in the list have 10 significant digits?

Comment: They already have 16 significant digits; they are just not all printed. Try `InputForm`, or otherwise change the print precision in Preferences. I wouldn't recommend jumping to arbitrary precision numbers without a good reason, nor reassigning precision using `SetPrecision` without a very good understanding of what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following,

```
N[NestList[Cos, 15/10, 10], 10]

{*
{1.500000000,0.07073720167,0.9974991672,0.5424049923,0.8564697089,0.6551088018,
0.7929816458,0.7017241683,0.7637303113,0.7222610821,0.7503128857}
*}

SetAccuracy[NestList[Cos, 1.5, 10], 10];
SetPrecision[NestList[Cos, 1.5, 10], 10];


NumberForm[NestList[Cos, 1.5, 10], {10, 10}]

{*
{1.5000000000,0.0707372017,0.9974991672,0.5424049923,0.8564697089,
0.6551088018,0.7929816458,0.7017241683,0.7637303113,0.7222610821,0.7503128857}
*}
```

**Edit**
With F1 or ?? you can find more information:

```
?? SetAccuracy
```

[image]

```
?? Accuracy
```

[image]

```
?? SetPrecision
```

[image]

```
?? Precision
```

[image]

```
?? NumberForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: May I ask "What is the difference between precision and accuracy?"

Comment: @David, My Pleasure, see my Edit.